# How to convert this json String to normal java arraylist using gson

Tags: java, json

I tried to convert following JSON string into Array and got following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory at
>   net.sf.json.AbstractJSON.(AbstractJSON.java:54) at
>   net.sf.json.util.CycleDetectionStrategy.(CycleDetect‌​ionStrategy.java:36)
>   at net.sf.json.JsonConfig.(JsonConfig.java:65) at
>   net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:84)

**JSON:**

```
[  
   {  
      "file_name":"1.xml",
      "file_ext":"application/octet-stream",
      "sr_no":"0.1",
      "status":"Checked ",
      "rev":"1",
      "locking":"0"
   },
   {  
      "file_name":"2.xml",
      "file_ext":"json/octet-stream",
      "sr_no":"0.2",
      "status":"Not Checked ",
      "rev":"2",
      "locking":"1"
   },
   {  
      "file_name":"3.xml",
      "file_ext":"application/json-stream",
      "sr_no":"0.3",
      "status":"Checked ",
      "rev":"1",
      "locking":"3"
   },
   {  
      "file_name":"4.xml",
      "file_ext":"application/octet-stream",
      "sr_no":"0.4",
      "status":"Checked ",
      "rev":"0.4",
      "locking":"4"
   }
]
```

**Code:**

```
JSONArray nameArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(output);
System.out.println(nameArray.size());
for(Object js : nameArray)
{
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) js;
    System.out.println("File_Name :" +json.get("file_name"));                                         
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't even a question but a work request.

Comment: At least show your current work, and tell us what problems you're having with it. Don't post a lazy question that shows no evidence of effort

Comment: Sorry to say but this is not work request actually i have tried the answer and got exception                                                                    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
 at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON.<clinit>(AbstractJSON.java:54)
 at net.sf.json.util.CycleDetectionStrategy.<clinit>(CycleDetectionStrategy.java:36)
 at net.sf.json.JsonConfig.<clinit>(JsonConfig.java:65)
 at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:84)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a java class with entities are: `file_name, file_ext, sr_no, status, rev, locking` in string type.

```
 public class TestJson {

        private String file_name, file_ext, sr_no, status, rev, locking;

        //get & set
        }
}
```

Then you call:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = your json string;
    TestJson[] respone = new Gson().fromJson(json, TestJson[].class);
    for (TestJson s : respone) {
       System.out.println("File name: " + s.getFile_name());
    }
}
```

So, you have a list of object you want.

Comment: can u please help me with example as i have created the class jut wan to know how to get list of object through code.

Comment: i'm not really to understand your mean, can u talk your mean clearly more?

Answer (score 6):

I know the question is about converting JSON String to Java Array, but I would like to also answer about how to convert the JSON String to an ArrayList using the Gson Library.

Since I spend a good amount of time in solving this, I hope my solution may help others.

My JSON string looks similar to this one -

[image]

I had an object named `StockHistory`, and I wanted to convert this JSON into an ArrayList of `StockHistory`.

This is how my `StockHistory` class looked -

```
class StockHistory {    
 Date date;
 Double open;
 Double high;
 Double low;
 Double close;
 Double adjClose;
 Double volume;
}
```

The code that I used to convert the JSON Array to the ArrayList of `StockHistory` is as follows -

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken< ArrayList<StockHistory> >(){}.getType();
List<StockHistory> history = gson.fromJson(reader, listType);
```

Now if you are reading your JSON from a file, the reader's initialization would be -

`Reader reader = new FileReader(fileName);`

and if you are just converting a string to JSON object then, the reader's initialization would simply be -

`String reader = "{ // json String }";`

Hope that helps. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I have to say your question is quite "ugly" and next time please improve your question's quality.

**Answer:**

Try to use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

If you have a java class to describe your items in the list:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
YourClass[] yourClasses = mapper.readValue(YourString, YourClass[].class);
```

Then convert the array to a List.

If you don't have a java class, just you LinkedHashMap instead.

Comment: GSON also has a formJson() method