# How to count the same json value and show it in textview?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have a JSON data and i want to count the json data if have a same value ?

```
{
"data": [
        {
            "ID": 47,
            "desa": "Benteng Selatan",
            "kecamatan": "Benteng"
        },
        {
            "ID": 48,
            "desa": "Benteng Selatan",
            "kecamatan": "Benteng"
        },
        {
           "ID": 49,
            "desa": "Benteng Utara",
            "kecamatan": "Benteng"
        },
        {
            "ID": 50,
            "desa": "Garaupa",
            "kecamatan": "Bontomatene"
        }
    ]
}
```

And show in text view, like :
Benteng Selatan and Benteng : 2,
Benteng Utara and Benteng : 1,
Garaupa and Bontomantene : 1

Comment: Please include the code for what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

By parsing your json string create an ArrayList Of Object.
See parsing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39657197/3926727).

Then use the following [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21678611/3926727) to group your data by value.